# firmware bug error after booting Ubuntu 18.04 from USB

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, usb-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside my Windows 10.
I booted my computer from my USB and then I got an error:

```
[firmware bug] ACPI region doesn't cover the entire command/response buffer
```

How can I fix this problem?

My BIOS is from MSI since 2018.

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422607/322816) suggests that you should turn the Windows "Fast Boot" off. Have you tried that?

Comment: @user3140225  i have been tried it but nothing happen.